# Как выполнять функцию в очень точный период времени Python

Tags: python, datetime, время

Задача: Ровно в 11 часов, 0 минут, 0 секунд, 100 миллисекунд должно происходить действие

Моё решение:

```
import datetime as dt
from time import sleep
 
# Время срабатывания часы, минуты, секунды
h, m, s = 11, 0, 0
 
alarm_time = dt.datetime(dt.datetime.now().year, dt.datetime.now().month, dt.datetime.now().day, h, m, s)
 
while True:
    if dt.datetime.now() >= alarm_time:
        sleep(0.1)
        print('Какое-то действие')
        break
```

Срабатывает через раз. Там отправляется запрос по API и если немного раньше, или позже - не проходит, так и понимаю, что мой будильник не точный

Как можно сделать будильник более точным?

Comment: А время и там куда отправляете запрос и у вас синхронизировано по ntp? Если время расходится с сервером, то как точно ни посылай запрос, толку не будет.

Comment: Даже не подумал об этом. Спасибо за идею, попробую покопать в этом направлении

Comment: Кроме того, формирование и посылка запроса тоже могут занимать какое-то время. Мне вообще кажется странной идея такой точной синхронизации запроса по времени. Да и вообще синхронизация запроса по времени. Если только это не криптобиржа и прочий трейдинг. Может заранее запрос подготавливать как-то. И чуть раньше посылать. Даже не знаю. Но сначала синхронизировать время, да.

Comment: Да, как раз с трейдингом связано

Comment: я бы написал тут простенькую апишку и взял бы библиотеку стороннюю, вроде crontab, background tasks. либо же celery

Comment: Вычислите аргумент для `sleep` и выполните его один раз. Цикл не нужен.

Comment: А, ну собственно да. Да и вообще используйте библиотеку `schedule` https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Попробую. Спасибо